# $F:A\rightarrow B$ be compact operator. Show closure subset of $B$ contains $0$.

Tags: functional-analysis

> $A,B$ are Banach spaces, $A$ infinite dimensional and $F:A\rightarrow B$ a compact linear
>   operator. Show that the closure of $\{Fx:||x||=1\}\subset B$ contains
>   $0$.

I've managed in a previous assignment, to show there is a sequence $(a_n)_n$ in $A$, such that $||a_n||=1$ and $||a_n-a_m||\geq 1$ for all $n,m\geq 1$, however I'm having trouble continuing with the above exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Assume for the contrary that there exists $\varepsilon>0$ such that $\|Fx\|\geq\varepsilon$ whenever $\|x\|=1$. Then show that $\|Fa_n-Fa_m\|\geq\varepsilon$ for all $n,m\geq1$. Use this to obtain a contradiction.